# Digitally sign a PDF with a smart card in a web application

Tags: c#, pdf, web-applications, certificate, smartcard

Trying to automate an unnecessarily manual process in which I email about 1000 users a PDF, they fill it out and sign it with a smart card and send it back to me. then I have to review, etc... even tracking who sends the emails back is a herculean task.

I am hoping to create a webform the users fill out and digitally sign and then I convert to PDF without having to download/upload the PDF. Is this possible in a C#.net **web application**?

if not, is there a clean way to scrape an email box for subjects, and then download the attachments to a server to begin processing?

any alternatives that you can think of?

Comment: The best way is to have the user put results directly into a database.  So the user will fill out a form and then press a submit button which put the data into the database.  So the user can submit the for to a webpage that will automatically store the response.  See following : https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/collecting-pdf-form-data.html

Comment: this looks like it may be helpful. thanks. Can I centrally distribute the file from a webapp? Ideally, I would like to fill out the form with profile data I manage, then have them only confirm and sign the form. Once I have the digitally signed form, I will analyze the data and do additionally processing

Comment: There is no reason that you cannot put System.Net.Mail library into a webapp to distribute the form as an email.

Comment: " sign it with a smart card" Is the PDF what needs to be digitally cryptographically signed? If so, then I assume you cannot sign the PDF yourself server side like others are suggesting, since you would not have access to the private key on the smart card. Instead, are you looking to do the cryptographic digital signing in the browser client side? On the PDF? Are the users doing PDF signing,as part of the ISO PDF standard? Or just signing the entire "blob"? Maybe elaborate on what they are doing now.

Comment: Singning a webform is not a convincing approach, since the sender has no reliable copy of what he signed. Even if he receives that later, it is too late to refuse signature in case of partial disagreement.

Comment: The problem I see is the user is signing the email/form and not the PDF. You have to send the user the PDF before signing. Otherwise you are somehow cheating. Option: Send email/form, generate PDF base on response and use a link to sign it with a webapp or similar, then store in database and notify you with user ID (based on PDF name or link you provided) that have signed.